# Trigger an API from Background Task at a Fixed time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-8

In my Windows Phone 8 App I need to trigger an API at sharp 2 A.M. But as of I analysed in Windows Phone 8 the scheduled task will trigger for every 30 minutes only and cant set a timer. Could anybody advice me how to achieve this in windows phone 8.
Please find my code below that I have tried so far.

The scheduled Task OnInvoke Method.

```
   protected async override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        GeoLocationService gs = GeoLocationService.InstanceCreation();
        repository = new HeartBeatRepository();
        HeartBeatModel _hbmodel = new HeartBeatModel();
        _hbmodel.MBeatName = "Heartbeat_";
        _hbmodel.MDataRoaming = "";
        _hbmodel.MDeviceID = "";
        _hbmodel.MFullName = "";
        _hbmodel.MLatitude = await gs.getlatitude();
        _hbmodel.MLongitude =await gs.getlongitude();
        _hbmodel.MTimeStamp = "";
        string userID = Convert.ToString(StateManagement.Current.GetValue("UserID"));
        if (userID.Length != 0)
        {
           await repository.PutHearBeat(userID, _hbmodel);
        }

        var curtime = DateTime.Now;
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60 - curtime.Minute));

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

The Class file which fires the API and here I have checked if the time is 2.00 A.M.

```
  public class HeartBeatRepository
  {
    public async Task<string> PutHearBeat(string userId, HeartBeatModel _heartbeatmodel)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt").Equals((DateTime.ParseExact("2.00", "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString())))

        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider(new HeartBeatHttpHandler(string.Format(Services.Services.PutHeartBeatData, userId)));
            var assetDetails = (string)await serviceProvider.PutData(_heartbeatmodel);  
            return assetDetails;            
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use PeriodicTask in windows phone 8 and set time interval 1 hour and then you can check if it is 2 or more then 2 PM but not more then 3PM for running your task. Let me know your view.

Comment: Instead of setting background task for each hour, is it possible something similar to remainder that fires at sharp 2.00 AM.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Could you please share me a code on how to set background agent for for triggering per hour.

Comment: Please refer to this http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/using-scheduled-task-agent-with-periodic-task-in-windows-phone-8/